# Variable should be a list of names but its not

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to get the name of the video game characters, here is the code

```
library(rvest)

link <- "https://www.warcraftlogs.com/reports/R2N1w6WMvtBTq7ac#fight=6&type=damage-done"
homepage <- read_html(link)
player <- homepage %>% html_nodes(".main-table-link") %>% html_text()
player
```

Here is what the console shows

> player
> character(0)

Comment: This looks like an example where the table content is generated dynamically using Javascript, so is not accessible to `rvest`. You may need to look at something like [RSelenium](http://joshuamccrain.com/tutorials/web_scraping_R_selenium.html).

Comment: I often go the "Network" tab of the dev-browser of my FF and look for data sources of type `json`. From there, note that some (from warcraftlogs.com) seem to have aspects of the table within the json structure. It may not have everything, but it may be a better option than using selenium (which can be hampered by timing problems, etc).